# How to Find ++(double plus) in string and replace with + (single) using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to remove double `++` from the string with single `+` using XSLT.

For example: `++31646331175`: I need the output of this as +31646331175.

If there is only a single plus or no plus at all, then ignore the string completely.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `replace` function (https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/replace.html) then? How did it fail?

Comment: I'm with Martin, here. `replace()` function seems the way to go. But, are you sure you want to replace `++` by `+` and not also "colapse" `+++` to `+`?

Comment: yes Martin replace giving me this error :
Description: Syntax error at char 0 in regular expression: No expression before quantifier,
i tried to use  <xsl:value-of select="replace($value, '+ +', '+')"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the XSLT-2.0 function `analyze-string`.
So the following XSLT code could do the job:

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <str>++0049134-343-285</str>
    <str>+00421335-645-784</str>
    <str>49134543-346-283</str>
    <str>++0042134-347-282</str>
    <str>++0041134-349-282</str>
</root>
```

Processing XSLT-2.0 file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/root/str">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="text()" regex="\+(\+.*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
+0049134-343-285
+0042134-347-282
+0041134-349-282
```

---

Another combination of templates can be the following utilizing the `matches` function:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />

<xsl:template match="str[matches(text(),'^\+\+[^+]+')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(),'+')"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This expression is even more precise because it excludes strings with three `+` or more at the beginning of the string.
I hope that this suffices your needs.

Comment: This seems over-complicated compared with a simple call on replace().